# Laravel: Page links doesn't works in second time

Tags: php, laravel, web, localhost

After 'php artisan serve' command, the page like 'localhost:8000/biodata' opens and when I click on some link to go to the other page, the current page keeps on loading all the time without giving me any error. When I tried to change the server ports like'localhost:8080/biodata' and then click on the link immediately, the next page opens but the links on the next page doesn't work and the page keeps on loading until I again change the server ports.

I'm practicing with this online version of code from any other link. Here is the code.

```html
index.blade.php:

    
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>List Biodata Siswa</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{ route('biodata.create') }}">Create New Biodata</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>{{$message}}</p>
      </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
      <tr>
        <th width = "50px"><b>No.</b></th>
        <th width = "300px">Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th width = "180px">Action</th>
      </tr>

      @foreach ($biodatas as $biodata)
        <tr>
          <td><b>{{++$i}}.</b></td>
          <td>{{$biodata->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$biodata->location}}</td>
          <td>
            <form action="{{ route('biodata.destroy', $biodata->id) }}" method="post">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{route('biodata.show',$biodata->id)}}">Show</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('biodata.edit',$biodata->id)}}">Edit</a>
              @csrf
              @method('DELETE')
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </table>

{!! $biodatas->links() !!}
  </div>
@endsection
```

```html
web.php:

    <?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
route::resource('biodata','BiodataController');
```

```html
BiodataController.php:

    
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Biodata;

class BiodataController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $biodatas=Biodata::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('biodata.index',compact('biodatas'))
                ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('biodata.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'location'=>'required'
        ]);
        Biodata::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('biodata.index')
                ->with('success','new biodata created successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $biodata = Biodata::find($id);
        return view('biodata.detail', compact('biodata'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $biodata = Biodata::find($id);
        return view('biodata.edit', compact('biodata'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required'
          ]);
          $biodata = Biodata::find($id);
          $biodata->name = $request->get('name');
          $biodata->location = $request->get('location');
          $biodata->save();
          return redirect()->route('biodata.index')
                          ->with('success', 'Biodata siswa updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $biodata = Biodata::find($id);
        $biodata->delete();
        return redirect()->route('biodata.index')
                        ->with('success', 'Biodata siswa deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

No error messages but the page keeps on loading.

Answer (score 0):

There is typo error in your `web.php` file. The last line is

```
route::resource('biodata','BiodataController');
```

It should be

```
Route::resource('biodata','BiodataController');
```